# Android ADT updation error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

'Install' has encountered a problem. An error occured during provisioning. This error occur each time when I trying to update ADT in eclipse ganymede. I tried with manual download of ADT plug-in also. Same thing happen...

Comment: This is a question or **SMS**? Try to use full words.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue. Go for Galileo and above versions of Eclipse as mentioned in the docs and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try 'link' method.Create a new folder named it 'MyPlugins' in the location of your myeclipse or eclipse,then put the adt you have downloaded in it but don't forget remove the `*.xml` files,next create a new file named 'adt.link' in the dropins folder with the contents '`path = (where you put you adt plugins)`'. At last , restart you IDE. Hope it will help.